# Does a 1/2" GE-type Combo AFCI circuit breaker exist?

Tags: circuit-breaker, afci

I've found 1" (THQL?) GE-type CAFCI breakers in stock, but can't find the GE-type CAFCI breakers in the slimmer 1/2" size (THQP?) for sale anywhere, not even out of stock listings. Do they make those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That's the gotcha with double-stuff breakers (GE thins, other tandems).

The small size of the breaker leaves no physical space for advanced functions like AFCI, GFCI, smart breaker, shunt trip, remote control breaker, etc.

That is why we recommend to *never* rely on the existence of double-stuffs, and choose your panel so you can do the entire job with full-size spaces and *have a bunch of spares*.  If this is new construcion, even though you have it already half wired in, now is the time to correct this mistake. Get a 40-space panel - **spaces are cheap**, we see houses that use 40, and plenty of spares are a GOOD thing not a sign of waste.  People add more stuff than you think.

40/42 space panels are the largest panels for which "spaces are cheap".  48+ space panels do exist, but are costly.

If you are married to that panel, your only option is to use an AFCI receptacle or deadfront mounted next to the panel.  If this is not a retrofit, the receptacle must be in a metal box, and the run between panel and receptacle must be metal conduit (EMT or FMC) or metal jacketed cable (AC or MC).  The deadfront is required when the circuit is required to serve only receptacles in that room (kitchen, bathroom, laundry, or garage typically).

Comment: 1990 or so house. The main panel is nearly full mostly using the thin breakers. Fortunately, I'm adding this circuit to a subpanel that's only half full. I simply had a thin space open and wanted to use it.